# Start inking in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto

I've developed a VSTO Addin for Word a few yeas ago. It uses the ink tool, so the user can write a signature directly on the document. I coded it in Visual Basic, because as of the time I didn't knew it better. Today i would take C#. I'm not a professional.

**How it works**

1. When the user opens a document, the addin looks for a certain keyword. It has about 30 chars and is hidden in the document.
2. If the keyword is found, it scrolls to the signature field and starts the inking tool, so the user can place the signature with a pen (prefered) or finger.
3. When the document is closed, it will be automatically uploaded to a server where it is stored as a pdf.

So: Open - Signate - Close. No other interaction is required.

**The weak point is**, I use CommandBars.ExecuteMso to do this. Now and then Microsoft changes something 
in the Ribbon Tab.

**I've used this in the last years**

For Word 2010 and 2016

```
Application.ActiveDocument.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("InkingStart")
```

For Word 365 - build 1803

```
Application.ActiveDocument.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("DrawInkMode")
```

For Word 365 - build 1806

```
Application.ActiveDocument.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FingerPaintingMode")
```

**Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore since build 12527.20194** (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-new-in-microsoft-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

In this build they added a lasso tool. When I execute CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FingerPaintingMode"), the lasso tool is active and not the pen.

[InkToolbox_lasso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQk1b.png)

You can execute this code as VBA in Word to see what i mean.

```
Sub InkTest()
    Application.ActiveDocument.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FingerPaintingMode")
End Sub
```

The weird thing is, when you physically click on FingerPaintingMode, the pen is active and not the lasso.

[InkToolbox_pen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q0Em.png)

**I think of two possible solutions**

1. Use a ink object directly and don't go over the ribbon. My preferred option, but im unable to find a way for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word/object-model
2. Select a Pen in the InkToolbox in the TabDrawInk tab. But it's a control type. So I can't use ExecuteMso. How could I do that?

Comment: You might want to use the [edit] link below the question to change this to VBA rather than VSTO as you'll reach a wider readership. What works in VBA can usually be "translated" to VB.NET. I assume you've tried the older ribbon control IDs to see if one of them might work (again)?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Sure, I've tried the older ribbon control IDs. They raise an exception.